# Would the produced message be copied to all brokers irrespective of the replication factor in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say I've a kafka cluster with 5 brokers and my replication factor is 3. With this configuration, if I send/produce a message, would it be copied to just 3 nodes or all 5 nodes but acknowledges after copying to 3 nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it will be replicated to 3 brokers. But acknowledgement is up to `ack` config of the producer and `min.insync.replicas` config.

`acks=0` means no acknowledgement. Producer sends message and don't care if it arrives to broker. You can lose messages.

`acks=1` means leader acknowledgement. Acknowledgement is sent when leader gets the message without waiting other replicas to replicate message.

`acks=all` means acknowledgement will be sent when all in-sync-replicas write the message (leader waits in-sync-replicas to replicate)

`min.insync.replicas` means minimum number of in-sync-replicas to produce messages.

For example: 
If you have 3 brokers and replication factor of a topic is 3 and min.insync.replicas is 1, then at the beginning the messages you produce are sent to leader and 2 replicas replicate it. But in case of broker failure or slowness in some of the brokers your number of in-sync-replicas can be just 1. At that point even you set acks=all your messages will be stored just in leader. (until the problem in brokers fixed and they catch up the leader)

So minimum recommended configuration to avoid message lost is having 3 brokers and this config:

- `topic replication factor=3`
- `min.insync.replicas=2`
- `acks=all`

But if you want 3 replicas to get acknowledgement in any case, then this configuration will be fine:

- `numer of brokers in cluster=5`
- `topic replication factor=3`
- `min.insync.replicas=3`
- `acks=all`

**With this config you can also tolerate up to 2 broker failures in cluster.